# Getting BitmapImage PixelHeight Property causes Initialization Issues

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graphics, imaging

I have a BitmapImage that I want to get the PixelHeight and PixelWidth properties so I can determine whether it has a landscape or portrait layout.  After I determine its layout, I need to set either the height or width of the image to get it to fit into my image viewer window without distorting the height:width ratio.  However, it appears I have to call BeginInit() in order to do anything with my image.  I have to call EndInit() to get the PixelHeight or PixelWidth properties and I cannot call BeginInit() more than once on the same BitmapImage object.  So how can I possibly set my image, get the height and width, determine its orientation and then resize the image?

Here the chunk of code that I have been working with:

```
image.BeginInit();
Uri imagePath = new Uri(path + "\\" + die.Die.ImageID + "_" + blueTape + "_BF.BMP");
image.UriSource = imagePath;
//image.EndInit();
imageHeight = image.PixelHeight;
imageWidth = image.PixelWidth;
//image.BeginInit();
// If the image is taller than it is wide, limit the height of the image
// i.e. DML87s and all non-rotated AOI devices
if (imageHeight > imageWidth)
{
    image.DecodePixelHeight = 357;
}
else
{
    image.DecodePixelWidth = 475;
}
image.EndInit();
```

When I run this, I get this run-time exception:

> InvalidOperationException:
>
> BitmapImage initialization is not complete. Call the EndInit method to
>   complete the initialization.

Does anybody know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Why do you need to set `DecodePixelWidth` or `DecodePixelHeight` at all? Can't you simply put the image into an `Image` control with an appropriate size?

Comment: It seems like it would be easier to just load the image in its original dimensions and then use a ScaleTransform later on to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: @Clemens:  If I don't set DecodePixel(Height/Width) propert(y/ies), my image will be its normal size and will not fit into the panel correctly.  My image will be either 1216x1616 or 1616x1216 depending on the image.  I need the maximum length of any side to be no more than 475 pixels.

Comment: The Image control will automatically scale the bitmap, according to its [Stretch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, what you want to do is not possible without decoding the bitmap twice.

I guess it would be a lot simpler to just decode the bitmap to its native size and then set the size of the containing Image control as needed. The bitmap is scaled appropriately, as [`Stretch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.stretch.aspx) is set to `Uniform` (since both width and height of the Image control are set, `Stretch` could as well be set to `Fill` or `UniformToFill`).

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage(new Uri(...));

if (bitmap.Width > bitmap.Height)
{
    image.Width = 475;
    image.Height = image.Width * bitmap.Height / bitmap.Width;
}
else
{
    image.Height = 475;
    image.Width = image.Height * bitmap.Width / bitmap.Height;
}

image.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
image.Source = bitmap;
```